# Getting error in place order There was an error processing your order. Please contact us or try again later. magento 1.7

Tags: magento

error log 
Notice: Use of undefined constant tmp - assumed 'tmp'  in /home3/dishapub/public_html/includes/src/__default.php on line 60532

In line 60532 line -  return new $backendClass($backendOptions);
does anyone can provide soluion? 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you've not got permissions to write to your tmp folder.

Look in /lib/Zend/Cache/Backend.php and you'll see a method called getTmpDir(), that loops through all the places that Magento thinks your temp folder could exists.

Usually the folder is named "tmp" and is on the root, so check if it's there and that it has read and write permissions, if it's not, then you'll have to find where your temp folder is and if it's in the method list, and if it has read/write permissions.